# Caching Pandas Dataframe by Serialization or In-memory KV Store

Tags: python, caching, pandas, redis

Which method of caching pandas DataFrame objcts will provide the highest performance? By storing it to a flat file on disk using `pickle`, or by storing it in a key-value store like Redis?

Answer (score 2):

I have a DF of ~ 1 GB of plain text data. Assuming the dumping to disk is always slower than reading I compared HDF5 write performance with pickle.
HDF5 took 35 sec while pickle did 190 sec. So, you could consider using HDF5 instead of pickle

Comment: Wes McKinney reported that HDF5 is the best for pandas, at a talk he gave recently.

Comment: Is HDF5 still the preferred format? Or is [Feather](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2016/03/feather-a-fast-on-disk-format-for-data-frames-for-r-and-python-powered-by-apache-arrow/) now preferred. The linked blog post is also by Wes.